# A submodule of finitely generated modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

$A\subseteq B\subseteq C$ are three commutative rings. $C$ is finitely generated as $A$-module. Is it true that $B$ is also finitely generated as $A$-module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = k[X_1, X_2, \ldots]$ be a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables, and let $C = A[Z]/(Z^2)$.

$C$ is finite over $A$, but there are lots of intermediate subrings that aren't.  For example, take $B = A[X_1Z, X_2Z,\ldots]$.

Comment: $B$ is still finitely generated by $1$ and $Z$ as an $A$-module.

Comment: @user150248 $ B $ does not contain $ Z $, so no.

Comment: @Starfall Oh, I should have noticed this ...